# Where can I find an in-depth tutorial on DSLR photography?

Tags: tutorial

Now I am a proud owner of Nikon D5300 DSLR equipped with an 18-55 kit lens. This is the first time I am dealing with DSLR. I don't want to use as a mere point-n-shoot camera, but want to use it to its fullest extent. I feel the need of taking a full-length, in-depth online free photography course which will take me to the DSLR world. Can anyone please suggest me any such course which explores the key areas in DSLR photography?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the Nikon Articles. It can be the next thing you look at after y[our camera's specific tutorial](http://imaging.nikon.com/support/digitutor/d5300.html). Some topics include:
Lenses: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Query/h4lfxztn/nikkor-lenses.html
ISO: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Query/gyqh325g/iso.html
Aperture: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Query/h4l7gjbw/aperture.html
Close-up: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Query/h4l7gjcj/close-up.html
there are many more with well-explained general information.

Another site you might wish to look at is Digital Photography School, especially this tutorial:
http://digital-photography-school.com/megapost-learning-how-to-use-your-first-dslr/

The Adorama Learning Center has solid info on the use of DSLR's organized into a variety of topics. Lots of video to make it easy. http://www.adorama.com/alc/0014511/article/nikon-d5300-dx-format-dslr-product-overview

These should give you a starting place. There are many more great sites, although you sometimes have to sort through a bit of clutter to find the best ones. Good luck and enjoy your new equipment!

Answer (score -1):

My answer would be the way I learnt (we are all "STILL LEARNING , BY THE WAY ") AND I COULD'NT RECOMEND IT MORE.
U-TUBE, .....GO ON TO U TUBE AND TYPE IN ANYTHING YOU WISH TO KNOW, you'll be amazed at what you can learn.. heres a link to just one of many... good luck
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkhQK_8pu9U

Comment: Please don't give link-only answers - we strongly prefer answers to be self-contained. And yes, I know the question is asking for links, which is why it's shortly going to be closed.

Comment: how is it a link only answer when I suggested a tutorial that he asked for  ... read it properly instead of being to quick to deny  clever clogs.. you know what ?  if this is made up of people like you , I'd rather not be part of it  GOOD BYE !